# ASP.net MVC Change in URL of the application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

the current application on MVC can be accessed through URL Like:
www.someserver.com/myapplication

Now there is a request to change it to a new URL: 
www.someserver.com/NEWFOLDER/myapplication

so my question is how will the MVC behave, will I have to make any routing changes ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

If your links are application-relative, for instance

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/myAreaName/index/")">My Area</a>
```

then you shouldn't have any problems.

If you've used site-relative links,

```
<a href="/myAreaName/index/">My Area</a>
```

They'll break.

Comment: How about if I have "../Content/Images/myImage.gif" ?

Comment: That's folder-relative (.. = "go up one from here"), so it *should* work. Try it and see.

Answer (score 2):

@David has the correct solution. I also keep the URL in the config file as an app setting for use in certain situations.

```
<%: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebsiteURL"] %>/Content/Images/a.png
```

Comment: Earlier we had it in the config..but then we changed. It is now myVirtualDirectory = String.Concat(lProtocolName + HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME"), HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath, "/")..... I hope works

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't as long as your application root moves (i.e. in IIS) and your URLs all properly specified in helper methods, prefixed with "~" where appropriate.

For example, a URL in an MVC app that is specified like "~/images/foo.jpg"  will resolve to "www.someserver.com/images/foo.jpg" in your current scheme.  Under the new scheme, if properly re-rooted in IIS, it will resolve to "www.someserver.com/NEWFOLDER/images/foo.jpg".

If you've used absolute or strictly relative URLs, however, you may be out of luck.